# if condition in php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

what i am willing my code to do is to subtract that stock number in database and if there is no stock ; dont subtract
here is my code:

```
<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$hostname = "localhost"; 
//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
$car = $_GET['buycar'];
$conn =mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("pro");
$res1 = mysql_query( "select *from `cars` where name = '$car'")
or die("failed to query database".mysql_error());
$x = mysql_fetch_assoc($res1);

if($x=0) {
    echo "This Car is Not Available"    ;
} else {
    $res = mysql_query( "UPDATE cars SET stock=stock -1 WHERE name='$car'") or die("failed to query database".mysql_error());
    $result = mysql_query("select * from `cars` where name = '$car'")
    or die("failed to query database".mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            echo "Name: " . $row["name"].  " - Price: " . $row["price"]. " - Speed: " . $row["speed"]. " - stock: " . $row["stock"]. "<br>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "There is no cars found with this name !";
    }
    echo " Thank you for Purchasing our car";   
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: well, to prevent it from substracting when it's already *out of stock* you will need to use `transaction`..

Comment: Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), learn to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and consult your [Rubber Duck](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: please consider formatting your questions in a readable manner if you want people to help you here. A post like this won't attract anybody to help you.

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: If you know and like the old mysql functions in PHP  , switch to mysqlI  <<< thats an eye at the end. It is more similar to the old way than PDO is, and likely easier to switch in your code since it only takes adding the letter I to the function name and addiing your DB connection handle.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in this part of your code:

`if($x=0)`

That is an assignment and will always be `0`.

You need to use a comparison operator such as `==`or `===`.

I.e.:

`if($x==0)` --- `if($x===0)`

Make sure you do have a value for the `GET` array.

Plus, do heed the warnings in comments.

You're open to a SQL injection and working with a deprecated MySQL API which has been deleted in PHP 7.